# When rendering intro in composite view it wont render text

Tags: compositing-nodes

Im watching a tutorial on youtube about making an intro from scratch but when we are in compositing view and I hit F12 (render) it wont render the text, it will render the other 2 scenes tho. Can anyone help me figure out why? And how to fix it?

[image: compositingview]

This is how my nodes are set up and they are not complete yet but before i continue adding more that i want/need i would like to be able to see my rendered text?

[image: compositingviewrenderandtext]

My rendering looks like this but refuses to display the text to the right.

[image: Scene1settings]
[image: scene2settings]
[image: scene3settings]

Scene 1 is my text (Scene)
Scene 2 is the smoke (scene.001)
Scene 3 is the particles (scene.002)

Any and all help would be much appreciated. Also I am new to blender so if im doing something wrong here please guide me through it :)

(Edit: If I just continue until my final render will it affect my project at all?

Update: Final render will **NOT** display any text whatsoever)

Comment: You should provide a link to the tutorial.

Comment: @brockmann the link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBRMh5QZ1n8&t=187s&index=12&list=WL

Comment: Its almost like its not rendering the world as transparent